# Grails submitToRemote validation

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, grails

I use grails submitToRemote to post my form content using AJAx. I want to validate form content using my own function and if that function returns true execute the grails submittoRemote.

How can I do this? Any ideas? Maybe binding the function on before and if the value returned is false don't execute the AJAX. Please help

```
 <g:submitToRemote  class="button" update="resultset" value="Swarch" action="show" before=" validateForm()" />

function validateForm() {
  var form = dijit.byId('myForm');
        if(form.validate()) {
          return true;
        }else {
          alert('Form contains invalid data.  Please correct first');
          return false;
        }
          return true;
  }
```

To make things short. How can i abort the ajax call if the function returns false.

Comment: Have you tried `before="if(!validateForm()) return false;"`?

Comment: Yes! You're the man! Post the answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have a custom validation for your submitToRemote tag you can write your condition as follow `before="if(!validateForm()) return false;"`:

example:

```
<g:submitToRemote  class="button" update="resultset" value="Swarch" action="show" before="if(!validateForm()) return false;" />
```

Hope this helps